# Monorepo Version Tags Conventions

Tags: git, git-tag, gitversion

Is there a standard for using version tags in monorepos?  Is something along the lines of `1.0.0-myapp1`, and `2.1.0-myapp2` acceptable?  Or is there another way to differentiate versions between applications?

Comment: A tag corresponds to a commit, which in turn corresponds to the entire repo.  So it's not clear what it would mean to tag a **mono**-repo based on the names of individual components.

Comment: If each app needs a different version, that is a good sign that you need a repo for each of them. I would either use a single version schema for this repo or split the repo for each app.

Comment: Google uses a monorepo and they **have to** version each project independently.

Answer (score 73):

`tags` are organized in directories and files (all git references are, run `tree .git/refs/tags` to see that), so I would suggest naming the tags :

```
myapp1/1.0.0
myapp1/1.0.1
 ...
myapp2/2.1.0
myapp2/2.2.0
 ...
```

This will group versions for each app together, and some commands will treat the numbers "naturally" :

```
# list tags, sorted by version number :
$ git tag --list --sort="version:refname"
myapp1/1.0.2
myapp1/1.0.10
myapp1/2.0.0
myapp1/10.0.0
myapp2/1.0.0
myapp2/2.0.0
myapp2/11.0.0
```

---

If you want to avoid the "tags for myapp2" showing up when you inspect the log for myapp1, you may use `git log` with the `--decorate-refs=<pattern>` option:

```
# this will include tags starting with 'myapp1', and all branches :
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate-refs=refs/tags/myapp1 --decorate-refs=refs/heads
```

If you need this on a regular basis, you can add an alias for it :

```
$ git config alias.logmyapp1 log --decorate-...
```